# Cucumber tests and captcha: how to handle that?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, captcha

We are considering using Cucumber for testing web applications (not in rails, most of them are asp.net actually).

The applications are in production, our main goal is to test if everything is fine with the services, from time to time, infra people would run it.

We have two questions:

1) Is this a good use for cucumber? Do community people encourage this use of cucumber feature definitions?

2) We have some captchas in our applications. Is there an widely adopted solution for this common problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cucumber looks relatively new.  I am a Java person and have used Selenium, HtmlUnit, JWebUnit, etc.  Selenium runs in .net, ruby, java, and some other scripting languages.

Selenium has been around for a while (2004 whereas Cucumber is relatively new, 2007).

Selenium has an IDE so you can easily record tests in firefox, save them, and then run them in your integration tests.

I am biased towards Selenium, but it does a good job and allows you to test your applications in several browsers (firefox, safari, IE).  It also has support for distributing tests across several servers (if your environment is that large, it supports it).

Ideally, you would have developers or the infrastructure people writing the tests.  Then if you have a CI server, you could automatically run the tests you have recorded/written, and then continuously check your application still works as a whole.  This works really great for catching errors as soon as they happen so if the developer makes a change and breaks something out of his scope, it will be fresh in his or her head.

As far as CAPTCHA goes, there are various libraries out there.  I am unfortunately more knowledgeable with the Java equivalent and not so much with the .Net.  Don't write your own, there should be a library you can use.

Walter

Comment: Cucumber is underpinned by Webrat. Webrat is capable of driving many browser testing tools, including Selenium and Watir.

Comment: Cucumber and Selenium are very different in their approach to test driven development. Cucumber runs a business orientated DSL and abstracts the implementation out into step definitions which are most likely written in Ruby but can run in other languages such as PHP. While selenium may be a more mature product, it's probably not the most important difference. I've been using cucumber for a while now and Selenium for a little. I'm a cucumber man myself :)

Answer (score 1):

ad 1. in my opinion cucumber is great, also we were able to convince our customers to actually understand and verify the tests we wrote in cucumber. We used cucumber + watir for webtesting

ad 2. as far as captcha goes, do you mean how to ignore the captcha for testing? we do not show captcha for our own ip addresses, you could also always accept a specific value for the captcha if the request comes from your development or test environments ip

Comment: ad 1. I agree, Cucumber is a fantastic tool for communicating the features of your app to your client. If, however, you are not doing this, then I have found it to be an unnecessary overhead.

Comment: I disagree that it is overhead, because, this way you have a lasting (executable) documentation of your system, which is very valuable on the long term. Developers seem to have very short memories ;) sometimes even after a couple of months, they dont remember which way some feature was supposed to work (especially when the way changed a couple of times during implementation)

Comment: @Rodreegez There is a considerable overhead but I found it's very hard to measure its worthiness. If cucumber is saving time by preventing regression error (for example), how would you measure this? When would you stop evaluating the benefits of using cucumber against the overhead of implementing and maintaining it (project lifecycle)? Cucumber is not only a great tool for communicating features to your client but it's also a great design tool for developers (knowing when to stop).

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend Cucumber. I trained a team of developers and managers to use it on my last project (a PHP application). It worked very well in most cases.

I think your two questions are mutually exclusive. Captcha is designed to prevent something automated so you're going to have to solve that problem for which ever automated test runner you use. You can probably mock something up or work out how to disable it in your test environment. I would opt for the latter. I don't imagine it would be critical to cover your captcha in your test suite.